# Need Product list by manufacturer name or option id

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, collection, product-list

i am trying this code

```
<?php  
$manufacturerId = 28;
$attributeCode = 'manufacturer';
 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $manufacturerId);

// print all products
echo "<pre>"; print_r($products->getItems()); echo "</pre>";

    ?>
```

but get real solution

output of this code is

```
Array
( 
)
```

how can i get product list by manufacturer name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it where you cycle through the options of the attribute and get a product collection for each one:

```
$name = 'manufacturer';
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

foreach ($attributeOptions as $_option){
    echo $_option['label'];

    $productcollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter($name, $_option['value']);

    foreach ($productcollection as $_product){
        echo $_product->getName();
    }
}
```

This way is a bit slow so you may prefer to instead load a collection of all products and then sort them by the manufacturer attribute.

Comment: it's just give me manufacturer name only i didn't get any product

Comment: Updated the product collection to include the attributes for use in outputting.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this:-

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>28),
    ));
```

// print all products

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($collection->getData()); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $manufacturerId);
```

In your code  `Items()` did not give the result.

Please use `getAllIds()` function it give all manufacturer  type 28

Answer (score -1):

```
->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>26895)));
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Its good to describe the solution you are providing